# AssertJ and Mockito: check a slightly complex JTable event?

Tags: tdd, mockito, hamcrest, jmock, assertj

I'm working through the book "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests".

But I'm using AssertJ and Mockito instead of Hamcrest and jMock.

I had previously needed to check for the occurrence of one or more table events associated with row 0 of the `JTable`.

```
    // verify that one or more events in row 0 happen
    verify(listener, atLeastOnce() ).tableChanged(refEq(new TableModelEvent(model, 0)));
```

(NB I was kindly informed about `refEq` by Mureinik [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930835/mockito-equivalent-to-this-hamcrest-samepropertyvaluesas-jmock-with-idiom) a few days ago).

Now I need to check that precisely one `TableModelEvent` occurred on row 0, of the `TableModelEvent.UPDATE` type.  The book has:

```
one( listener ).tableChanged( with( aChangeInRow( 0 )));
```

... `aChangeInRow` appears to come from jMock.

NB `TableModelEvent` has a useful method `getType()`. Here's what I want to write:

```
    // verify that precisely one ***change*** event happens in row 0
    // *** CAVEAT: ERRONEOUS CODE ***
    verify( listener ).tableChanged(refEq(new TableModelEvent(model, 0))).getType().isEqualTo( TableModelEvent.UPDATE );
```

but this doesn't even compile ... what should I have written?

More generally, is there an AssertJ/Mockito technique for extracting a value passed as a parameter (here a `TableModelEvent`) to a verified method in order to subject it to whatever tests you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use Hamcrest You will have to write your own matcher veryfing the result of a getType method.

```
ArgumentMatcher<RockData> checkTypeMatcher = new ArgumentMatcher<TableModelEvent>() {


public boolean matches(Object arg0) {   
    //put more logic here
    TableModelEvent event = (TableModelEvent) arg0; 
    return event.getType() == TableModelEvent.UPDATE;
}
};

verify( listener ).tableChanged(Mockito.argThat(checkTypeMatcher) );
```

**UPDATE: Using ArgumentMatcher form Mockito.**

ArgumentMatcher class comes from Mockito.

Comment: Thanks... but (unless I've misunderstood) `Matcher` and `BaseMatcher` are indeed Hamcrest classes.  It may be that there is no Hamcrest-free solution (I'm too much of a testing newb at this point, hence the question) but I'd be quite surprised if so...

Comment: Right but You can use ArgumentMatcher class from Mockito. See my update above.

Comment: OK thanks ... to me, though, I'm just wondering whether there might not be an AssertJ technique which is more in the "fluent" spirit of AssertJ?  Which in my mind (as I say, I'm a newb) is not unconnected with my other problem, which is that your solution doesn't also check the row number where this update occurred... I just think there might be a solution which somehow does both, probably by "stringing" two AssertJ methods together.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito API works with Hamcrest matchers. You'll have to stick with them.

I don't really see a point of insisting on AssertJ matchers, but if you really want, you can capture the `ArgumentCaptor` and then use AssertJ.

```
ArgumentCaptor<TableModelEvent> cap = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(TableModelEvent.class);
verify(listener).tableChanged(cap.capture());

TableModelEvent value = cap.getValue();
assertThat(value).isNotNull();
```

Comment: Thanks... It's just that I'm quite confused as a testing newb with all these different frameworks.  I've read a few books on TDD and a couple of points have come up: first the nice readability of AssertJ, second the "fluent" (i.e. string them together) character of AssertJ methods, and thirdly some reported problems to do with conflicting versions of Hamcrest (e.g. JUnit is bundled with a particular Hamcrest when you use Gradle)... but if I have to get familiar with Hamcrest, so be it!

Comment: Hamcrest seems to be stalled. Even modern versions of Mockito are already decoupled from Hamcrest and don't have it as dependency (though you can still use them together if you want). AssertJ is still actively developed and have a lot of convenient matchers.